# Java - Equals list returning false?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, compare, list-comparison

I have this code that compares if the two lists have the same objects:

```
List<CcustoPrestadorOuImplDTO> implsNaConfig = configImplPermitida.getImplementos();
List<CcustoPrestadorOuImplDTO> implsNoApto = configuracaoImplementoDoApontamento.getImplementos();
Collections.sort(implsNaConfig, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCdCcusto()));
Collections.sort(implsNoApto, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getCdCcusto()));

if ( implsNaConfig.equals(implsNoApto)  ){
    return true;
}
```

In debbuging I have this situation:

[image]

As you can see, both lists have the same object with the same properties.

But the code that compares if the two lists are equals its always returning false.

I tried with containsAll() method but for some reason returns false too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `CcustoPrestadorOuImplDTO` class have its own `equals` method defined?  It will need to, to make this work.

Comment: also, the elements order matters

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, you were right. There wasn't any equals method defined in the class. I put and it worked. Thank you. Post as an answer so I can mark.

Comment: I don't have time.  But you can post your own answer.  I'll upvote it if it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DawoodibnKareem asked, I will post the solution:

The reason for always getting "false" in the `if ( implsNaConfig.equals(implsNoApto)  )` its because my `CcustoPrestadorOuImplDTO` class didn't have the `equals` method implemented.

So I edited the class file and auto-generated the equals method and it worked.

The equals method in the CCustoPrestadorOuImplDTO class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    CcustoPrestadorOuImplDTO that = (CcustoPrestadorOuImplDTO) o;
    return Objects.equals(cdCcusto, that.cdCcusto) &&
            Objects.equals(deCcusto, that.deCcusto) &&
            Objects.equals(grupoOperativo, that.grupoOperativo) &&
            Objects.equals(deGrupoOperativo, that.deGrupoOperativo);
}
```

And this is the HashCode() method:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(cdCcusto, deCcusto, grupoOperativo, deGrupoOperativo);
}
```

It's really simple, but I did not even think that this was the cause of the issue.

Thank you everybody.

Comment: Don't forget to implement `hashCode()` as well.

Comment: I personally would also add Comparable interface inside your class, as opposed to using Comparator (though it's also fine)